Pandas Merge two DFs on common ID
I'm merging two dataframes, one has 3 rows and the other has 100+ rows. What I am attempting to do is look at the IDs in DF1 and grab the corresponding ID data in DF2 and merge them together, ignoring the other rows. What seems to be happening it is just pulls in the first 3 rows form DF2 and isn't matching on the IDs.
DF1
id  season             start_datetime          home_team             away_team  home_odds  away_odds     ou
384813    2024  2024-06-04T19:00:00-04:00  Connecticut Sun W  Washington Mystics W        1.1       7.25  153.0
384814    2024  2024-06-04T20:00:00-04:00      Chicago Sky W    New York Liberty W        3.4       1.33  164.5

DF2
id  season             start_datetime          home_team             away_team  home_rest    away_rest
384811 .......
384812 .......
384813    2024     2024-09-19      Connecticut Sun W  Washington Mystics W       1.0       1.0
384814    2024     2024-09-19    Chicago Sky W    New York Liberty W      1.0       1.0
384815 ......
384816 ......

I want to look up the IDs in DF1 and merge all data from DF1 with home_rest and away_rest from DF2 into a new DF.
newdf = pd.merge(df1, df2[['id', 'home_rest', 'away_rest']], left_on='id', right_on='id', how='left')

This is making a new DF, but newdf is not bringing in the data for home_rest or away_rest
newdf = pd.merge(nba_games_combined, nba_rest[['id', 'home_rest', 'away_rest']], how='inner', left_index=True,
                     right_index=True, suffixes=('', '_remove')).set_index('id')

This makes a new DF but brings in the WRONG data for home_rest and away_rest, it is just taking the data from the top rows.
Same with
newdf = pd.concat([nba_games_combined, nba_rest], axis=1, join='inner')

I'm obviously not understanding something here with the logic involved or going about it incorreclty.

Does this answer your question? Pandas Merging 101

Not exactly, I've read though that many times but don't see what I'm missing.

Source data was bad and I changed my merge to
df3 = df1.merge(nba_odds[['id', 'home_odds', 'away_odds', 'ou']]).merge(df2[['id', 'home_rest', 'away_rest']], on='id')

